# How did CLRS book conclude BUILD_MAX_HEAP is not asymptotically tight with O(n log n)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heap, heapsort

[image]

CLRS book page no 157 3rd edition. My question is not regarding why is complexity of BUILD_MAX_HEAP is O(n) nor the proof. However, towards the systematic approach they used to conclude that it is not asymptotically tight at O(n log n). Logically it is right to say O(n log n).

The point i’m stuck is how did they get the intuition that, there is much better tighter upper bound. If it wasn’t for the CLRS explanation. Will we ever know ?

The core of my question regarding the intuition we have to make self aware that there is a much better tighter bound.

Are we suppose to hunt for tighter tighter bound for every algorithm we find ? I mean a logical conclusion for a laymen is O(n log n). How can he go further from here. Have i missed some basics in between ?

Comment: Not sure about the book, but if you look at e.g. [this MIT worksheet](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/fall10/handouts/recitation10-8.pdf) you'll notice that although `MAX-HEAPIFY` is `O(lg n)`, the `n` that is being used there is subtly different for each call that is made to it by `BUILD-MAX-HEAP`. Early calls will use a much smaller `n` than the `n` used to define the runtime for `BUILD-MAX-HEAP`.

Comment: `Are we suppose to hunt for [ever/y/thing`]?` No. It doesn't hurt to try to establish a lower bound - it may coincide with the upper. If measurements suggest "average" behaviour to be decidedly better, there's cause to investigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how did they get the intuition that, there is much better tighter upper bound.

I don't know how did they specifically get the intuition, but here is one way of seeing it (possibly with the benefit of hindsight).

`Build-Heap`'s complexity, at least intuitively, seems similar to

*T(n) = T(n / 2) + Θ(n)*

whose solution is *T(n) = Θ(n)*.

(Note that what follows is not a proof, but only intuition!)

Say you have a binary heap with *n / 2* elements, and whose last row is full, and you double the number of elements. This will basically add another row.

How does doubling the number of elements (in this case, at least), change the time of `Build-Heap`?

- Because of the penultimate row, there are *Θ(n)* more calls to `Heapify`, but each one obviously does *O(1)* work.
- For the rows above the penultimate row, the *Θ(n)* calls to `Heapify` basically operate as before, but each one has another *O(1)* work at the end (the path is longer by 1).

> Are we suppose to hunt for tighter tighter bound for every algorithm we find ?

To some extent, yes. Finding tighter bounds for algorithms always generates interest. Note that for `Heapsort`, there was even interest in [proving](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~paulv/papers/sorting.pdf) that one variation used *2 n log(n) (1 - o(1))* operations, whereas another one used *n log(n) (1 + o(1))* operations, even though both are *Θ(n log(n))*.

> I mean a logical conclusion for a laymen is O(n log n).

Laymen probably mostly use algorithms which have been extensively studied by experts.

> How can he go further from here.

There's probably no algorithm for finding bounds on algorithms. One possible approach would be to plot the running time for increasing values of *n*, and see how the running time looks. If it looks linear, it's not a proof, but it's an indication for what to look for.

Comment: Thank you, appears make sense to an extend now. Since no body else have answered i'm accepting this. :) grateful for your time.